# Remove characters from string with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have this header:

```
>tr|G3Q381|G3Q381_GASAC Uncharacterized protein OS=Gasterosteus aculeatus PE=4 SV=1
```

and I was thankfully helped on here to get it to:

```
 >G3Q381_GASAC
```

but now I need to cut the last two letters off of the previous format like this:

```
  >G3Q381_GAS
```

Is it possible from the initial long header (not middle truncated one) to get it to this?

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Is this only one header or more with similar pattern? If only one then just write `echo  '>G3Q381_GAS'` and you are done. If there are more headers then show us more of them catch similarities. Remember that `sed` or other text processing tool works on **regular** expressions, i.e. there must be some regularities.

Comment: You are right, I apologize. After the header there are 4 more lines. I just want to change the header of these sequences while keeping the carrot.  There are many more lines with this header following the same pattern

Comment: This is unanswerable in its current form as it presumes a middle step that is not documented, ie., how you arrive at the current (truncated) header. Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it acceptable, but you can remove everything before the second pipe `|`, and everything after the first space minus 2 characters :

```
sed -e 's/^[^|]*|/>/' -e 's/^[^|]*|/>/' -e 's/.. .*$//'
```

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately. It actually deletes the lines after the header even though it does delete the last two characters. |I3KMH5|I3KMH5_ORE
Plus I need the carrot '>' there

Comment: I edited it, it should do what you want now

Comment: okay i'll check. Thank you for the rapidity

Comment: Thank you sir this worked. Thanks.  Soon I will read up on Sed and not have to bother you guys.

Comment: i was trying to upvote it but it says I don't yet have the reputation

Comment: okay got it, it's the other arrow. ahhaa

Comment: Don't worry, it's not a big deal ;)